# Inline editable OneToOne relation in sonata admin bundle

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, sonata-admin

The sonata admin bundle provides functionality to edit entities inline when they are associated by a OneToMany relation. See http://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/form_field_definition.html#advanced-usage-one-to-many

Is there any way to get the same functionality for a OneToOne relation? So that I would be able to edit a child entity within my parent entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you must use sonata_type_admin as field form type ... http://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/form_types_and_transformers.html

Comment: Already tried that. This doesn't give me a form for inline editing :-(

Comment: The strange thing is that nothing happens if I switch between the types sonata_type_model and sonata_type_admin